# Black Screen on android emulator?

Tags: .net, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Whenever I start my emulator I'm getting this black screen and performance issues and I've enabled HyperV and all that stuff...

[image]

Comment: Have you tried making another emulator?

Comment: Hi, which version of api used for the emulator? You can create another api version(such as : `28`) to check whehter it shows. And also can refer to [Setting up the Android SDK for Xamarin.Android](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-sdk?tabs=windows#platforms-tab) check whether install the needed platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Tools->Android->Android Device Manager->select Emulator(Right
> click)->Factory reset

try it

Comment: This one worked for me, on NET MAUI, NET Core 6, year 2023. With Pixel 5 API 31, Android 12.0. Also, I wonder if it was just a memory problem that was solve by resetting the device...

Answer (score 0):

Try to press home button or power button on the side of the emulator

Answer (score 0):

Waiting normally fixes it for me. if you are not patient/ have the hardware to do it add more ram to your emulator 3536 is 3 Gig

ramsize = 3536

[image]